# How to put a border around MaterialSpinner Xamarin.Android?

Tags: xamarin.android, border, spinner

I have to give my `MaterialSpinner` the following border:
[image]

I have the following `MaterialSpinner`

```
<fr.ganfra.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    app:ms_arrowColor="#000000"
    app:ms_arrowSize="16dp"
    app:ms_floatingLabelColor="#A9A9A9"
    app:ms_floatingLabelText="Избор на група"
    app:ms_hint="Избор на група"
    app:ms_hintColor="#000000"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/material_spinner_border"/>
```

`material_spinner_border.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

    <!-- View background color -->
    <solid
        android:color="#000000" >
    </solid>

    <!-- View border color and width -->
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#000000" >
    </stroke>

    <!-- The radius makes the corners rounded -->
    <corners
        android:radius="2dp"   >
    </corners>

</shape>
```

When I run the app the border doesn't appear on screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to put a border around MaterialSpinner Xamarin.Android?

Set your `MaterialSpinner` `ms_arrowColor` color as white to hide the arrow:

```
<fr.ganfra.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        app:ms_floatingLabelColor="#A9A9A9"
        app:ms_floatingLabelText="Избор на група"
        app:ms_hint="Избор на група"
        app:ms_hintColor="#000000"
        app:ms_arrowColor="#ffffff"
        app:ms_arrowSize="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/material_spinner_border"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        />
```

Add your arrow image to your project, for example:

[image]

Then, modify your `material_spinner_border` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <layer-list>
      <item>
        <shape>
          <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#000000" />
          <corners android:radius="4dp" />
          <padding android:bottom="0dp" android:left="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:top="0dp" />
        </shape>
      </item>
      <item >
        <bitmap android:gravity="center|right" android:src="@drawable/myarrow" />
      </item>
    </layer-list>
  </item>
</selector>
```

[Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nxs4.png).

## Update:

Set spinner background after set the `Spinner` adapter will solve this issue:

```
string[] ITEMS = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5", "Item 6" };
var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, ITEMS);
adapter.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
var spinner = FindViewById<MaterialSpinner>(Resource.Id.spinner);
spinner.Adapter = adapter;

spinner.Background = Drawable.CreateFromXml(Resources, Resources.GetXml(Resource.Drawable.material_spinner_border));
```

Comment: @Profile3ForStack, could you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: I downloaded arrow image in all dimensions made the references in code to it but I still don't get the border. I tried to change the color of the frame various times but still nothing.

Comment: @Profile3ForStack, what's you mean "don't get the border"? Can you post a picture to describe this?

Comment: And how to make "Please choose group" initial spinner value?

Comment: @Profile3ForStack, you could try using my updated answer, if it still not works, I will give you a workaround to add the hint text in `Spinner`.

Comment: it was exactly as you said - nothing worked until i added it programatically and did it AFTER setting the adapter, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a picture what it looks like:

[image]

I forgot to tell you that my backgroung is dark if it matters

Comment: Did you need the drop item still has the same border effect? And could you please share a basic demo that can reproduce your problem? That would be really appreciated!

Comment: I only need rounded border around the spinner. Border around the arrow is not that important.

Comment: Do you mind using `Spinner` instead of `MaterialSpinner`? After changing the spinner type from `MaterialSpinner` to `Android.Widget.Spinner` it works perfectly on my side.

Comment: If you still want use `MaterialSpinner` to implement this feature you could check my updated answer, it works fine when I use `MaterialSpinner` on my side.